# Using Regex in Android Studio can't get the output

Tags: java, android, regex, android-studio

I am currently working on an app search button. The button is called srhButton, so once this button is clicked in the search area named (id = query) i would want the variable to check if the (id = query) is in my saved list, and print it out in my Output Ares (id = comment). my problem is my output won't change.

If just say the query is la(la), and if the list contains la(la), it needs to print yes in the comment area.

The code:

```
srhButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


                String searchQuery = query.getText().toString();
                String joined = TextUtils.join(",", savedList);
                Pattern ptrn = Pattern.compile("!*\\w*(^[^(]+);\"\\([^(]*?\\).*!;");
                Matcher matcher = ptrn.matcher(searchQuery);
                Matcher matcher1 = ptrn.matcher(joined);
                while (matcher.find()) {
                    if (matcher.group(0) == matcher1.group(0)) {
                        comment.setText("YES");
                    }
                    else
                        comment.setText("invalid number");

                    }
                }
```

Comment: `matcher1` is not run when you access `matcher1.group(0)`. Use `matcher1.find()` before.